# Change class for a core shape

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I'm trying to change class for **Pager** from `pager` to `pagination` as it's conflicting with bootstrap classes.

It's defined in `CoreShapes.cs` with

```
Shape.Classes.Add("pager");
```

I managed to add classes I need by overriding **Pager.cshtml**

```
@{
    // number of page number links to show, 0 means no link, 1 means only the current page, or more accepted.
    Model.Quantity = 5;
    Model.Metadata.Alternates.Clear();
    Model.Classes.Add("pagination pagination-sm");
    Model.Metadata.Type = "Pager_Links";
}
@Display(Model)
```

This results in list that has `class="pager pagination pagination-sm"`.

Is it possible for me to remove the `pager` class without modifying `CoreShapes.cs` or using javascript? Already tried without success:

```
Model.Classes.Clear();
```

Comment: Clearing classes should work. Did you try to put a breakpoint in there? What I'd suspect is that the classes that you are trying to suppress are actually being added later, i.e. as part of the call to `@Display(Model)`.

Comment: You are right, pager class isn't present in `Model.Classes` before the call to `Display(Model)`.

Comment: Then try to do the work from an override of Pager_Links instead of Pager.